# Every Nash equilibrium is Subgame perfect Nash equilibrium.

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

> Every Nash equilibrium is Subgame perfect Nash equilibrium.

This statement is wrong. I show this by an counter example.

[image]

Is this example enough and good to disprove this statements?

Please share your ideas with me.

Thank you

Note: in the paper, there is typo.

(Out, price war) is not SPNE, but NE. (In, accomodate) is NE and SPNE. So, NE set covers all SPNE. But, SPNE set doesnt cover all NE

Comment: You need to explain why your example is a counter-example

Comment: @whoisit (Out, price war) is not SPNE, but NE. (In, accomodate) is NE and SPNE. So, NE set covers all SPNE. But, SPNE set doesnt cover all NE

Comment: To disprove you need to show an example game + strategy profile that is a NE but is not a SPNE. Please elaborate on how is your example doing that? Do not reply to me, add those details in the question.

Comment: Please link to other versions when crossposting: https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/53529/every-nash-equilibrium-is-subgame-perfect-nash-equilibrium